# What has caused my csv load time to dramatically increase?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a monthly report formatted as a .csv file. It's file size is 90 MB.

It used to take around 10 seconds to open. Now it takes 4-5 minutes. When I convert it to an .xlsb, it takes 10 seconds. Does anyone have any theories on what is causing this?

Please note that between this month and last month I also upgraded my Excel 2013 x86, to **Excel 2013 x64**. When I get a colleague to open the file (on their x86 version), it takes 10 seconds. Unfortunately, no one else has a x64 bit version to test on. I have also disabled all add-ins to see if that was the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *90 Mgb*?

Comment: The size of the .csv file is 90MB

Comment: Is there any possibility of performing a clean uninstall followed by a clean install? "Upgrades" tend to leave behind clutter

Comment: That is something I could do, but it may take some time as I would have to open a ticket and go through the IT department. Will keep it as a last resort. Was just wondering if anyone else had experienced a similar issue...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting into safe mode with `/s` flag. You don't mention windows vs mac, but windows you can just change the path, *like* -

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Excel.exe" /s
```

You also may want to try repairing your installation. Additionally, it's been reported that disabling hardware acceleration *may* fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had to do a whole new windows and office installation which has fixed the problem.